# Categorizing data under a common date using MySql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a project management system but I got stuck trying to categorize the projects that share the same date. For example if I posted two projects today and two projects yesterday I want it to show like this:

```
2019-06-01:
project 1 
project 2
2019-05-31:
project 3
project 4
```

This is how the table looks like

```
------------------------------------------------
   id   |   project_name   |       date       |
   01   |   project 1      |    2019-06-01    |
   02   |   project 2      |    2019-06-01    |
   03   |   project 3      |    2019-05-31    |
   04   |   project 4      |    2019-05-31    |
------------------------------------------------
```

This is my code:

```php
<?php
  include "connect.php";


  $get_date = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `date` FROM `projects` WHERE `user_id` = '1' GROUP BY `date`");

  while($row = $get_date -> fetch_array()){

    $date = $row['date'];
    $string_date = strtotime($date);
    echo $only_date = date('Y-m-d', $string_date) . "<br/>";


    $get_project = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `user_id` = '1' && `date` = '$date' GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `date`");

    while($d_row = $get_project -> fetch_array()){
      $name = $d_row['project_name'];
      echo $name . "<br/>";


    }

  }

?>
```

This is the output of my code:

```
2019-05-30
project 3
2019-05-30
project 4
2019-06-01
project 1
2019-06-01
project 2
```

Comment: Get rid of the first query. Get rid of the GROUP BY and the date stuff on the second query. Just SELECT the rows that you want and handle everything else in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

**DLLs:**

```
DROP TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,project_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'project 1','2019-06-01'),
(2,'project 2','2019-06-01'),
(3,'project 3','2019-05-31'),
(4,'project 4','2019-05-31');
```

**Code**

```
<?php

include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT date
     , project_name
  FROM my_table
 ORDER
    BY date DESC
     , project_name; -- ORDER BY is not strictly necessary, as the ordering can be done in presentation code.
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $array[] = $row;
}

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $v){
  $new_array[$v['date']][] = $v['project_name'];
}

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [2019-06-01] => Array
        (
            [0] => project 1
            [1] => project 2
        )

    [2019-05-31] => Array
        (
            [0] => project 3
            [1] => project 4
        )

)
```

Obviously, you can stick with your PDO methods

Comment: nice explanation @Strawberry